# Errors while upgrading site mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My site http://world2build.hol.es i tried to upgrade mysql to mysqli so i changed
all of the mysql_ to mysqli_ but it broke the site

Answer (score -1):

With mysqli you have to send the connection with the query. Like this:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// Perform queries 
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons");
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName,LastName,Age) 
VALUES ('Glenn','Quagmire',33)");

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Other parts of the site is also broken. Ex: http://world2build.hol.es/Groups/ It has a header. I already changed the landing thing on my sire using your code

Comment: Yes, you're going to have to look at the errors and track down everywhere you are using the mysqli_ functions and add that second param.

Comment: Okay ill start doing that.